# How can I optimise 50+ fields(columns) for many tables?

Tags: database, optimization

This is a general database development question

History - I've already created a very similar system that I used a single "Component table" to encompass all the necessary fields for multiple components (works great) only have ~15 fields.

Current project - Each component has 40-60 very different fields.

Question - Would it be more efficient in terms of fetching, storing and manipulating data in a database;

Many tables with the specific fields for each component or a general component table comprised of 100+ columns then fetch the necessary fields when the specific component is mentioned?

This is for an SQLite DB on android, feel free to give me other ways of storing this stuff.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all the fields of a record are needed simultaneously, and only upon lookup of that one component, then put them together.

If the fields are cross-referenced to other components or you only need a few at a time, then consider a better-factored schema.

Optimizing a SQLite database inside an Android client application, you should follow the best practices of performance optimization: Create real-world (or fairly realistic) test cases and benchmark scientifically. Before making too much effort, identify a performance issue and automate the process of reproducing it, so you won't be chasing phantoms.